# $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the sphere $S^n$ are two Topologically homogeneous sets?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Ok, a set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is topologically homogeneous if for every $x,y \in X$, there exists a homeomorphism $f: X \to X $, such that $f(x)=y$.

The questions is, $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the sphere $S^n$ are two topologically homogeneous set??

$\mathbb{R}^n$ is topologically homogeneous. Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, take $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $f(x) =x + (y-x)$, that is, the translation of the vetor $y-x$. It's easy to see that $f$ is contínuos and $f^{-1}$ too and both are bijection. Then there exists a homeomorphism such that $f(x)=y$.

But in the sphere? Can I use the translation?

Another question is, why the interval $(0,1]$ isn't topologically homogeneous?

Comment: It'd be better to separate out the last question - but also to think about it further before posting. (For instance, which point in $(0,1]$ is a likely candidate for looking different than the other ones?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use stereographic projection.

Comment: It only works if both $x,y$ are distinct from the projection point.